# Can anyone tell me what's going wrong with this code?

Tags: java

This is the code snippet.I can't find anything wrong here...Can anyone please help?

```
while(num != 0) {
    rev = rev * 10;
    rev = rev + num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
}

if (num == rev)
    System.out.println("The number is Palindrome");
else
    System.out.println("The number is not Palindrome");
```

Comment: If you got any error show it, if you got wrong output explain it. 'can't find anything wrong here' does not help at all

Comment: You omitted critical information, such as what is the starting value of `rev`, and also, what is this algorithm supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that you are not storing the value of `num` variable before reversing it. As the `while` starts the `num` value starts changing. You should do this:

```
int temp = num; // storing the original value
int rev = 0; // initial value of rev
// --------
// while loop logic here
// --------
if(temp == rev) // change your condition here
// and you're good to go
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to initialize the value of `rev` because it is a local variable. Then you need to store the `num`'s value in a temporary value in order to compare it with your `rev`.
Here is a method with your piece of code:

```
public void isPalindrome(int num) {
        int rev = 0;
        int temp = num;
        while(num!=0)
        {
            rev=rev*10;
            rev= rev+num%10;
            num=num/10;
        }
        if(temp==rev)
            System.out.println("The number is Palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println("The number is not Palindrome");
    }
```